# GSP if check on possible null object

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following code

```
<g:if test="${cart == null || cart.isEmpty()}"> 
    Cart is Empty   
</g:if>
<g:else>
    ${cart.size()} items
</g:else>
```

but the first time I access the site (when cart is null) I get a "Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object" exception

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be rewritten as

```
<g:if test="${cart}"> 
    ${cart.size} items    
</g:if>
<g:else>
    Cart is Empty
</g:else>
```

If a variable is null or a Lists size is 0, it will be False according to the Groovy truth.